# How can you list all vm private ips in an AZURE subscription?

Tags: azure

[image]I want to list all the private IP addresses assigned to vms in a subscription, is there a way to do this?

ie via portal or cli ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PowerShell:

```
$vms = get-azvm
$nics = get-aznetworkinterface | where VirtualMachine -NE $null #skip Nics with no VM

foreach($nic in $nics)
{
    $vm = $vms | where-object -Property Id -EQ $nic.VirtualMachine.id
    $prv =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAddress
    $alloc =  $nic.IpConfigurations | select-object -ExpandProperty PrivateIpAllocationMethod
    if ($vm.Name -NE $null) {
        Write-Output "$($vm.Name) : $prv , $alloc"
    }
}
```

Using the portal.

1. Go to Virtual Machines
2. Edit Columns
3. Add Private IP Address

[image]

Comment: @itye1970 see provided image.

Comment: yes i also did the same but Private IP isnt listed in mine? i selected ALL and just see  ADKAutomation
ADKAutomationGUID
ADKAutomationName
AutomationAccountARMID
Created By
displayName
Kind
Location ID
ms-resource-usage
Project
Resource group
Resource group ID
Resource ID
Resource type
RSVaultBackup
Subscription
Subscription ID
Tags
WBS-Code
WorkLoad

Comment: Can you share a print screen in your question of what you see when you try to edit the columns in the Virtual Machines blade? Maybe its a lack of permissions.

Comment: sure but  i cant see option here to upload screenshot?

Comment: Take a screenshot and just paste it into your question.

Comment: @itye1970 you are at the All Resources blade and not the Virtual Machines blade